# Actualizar y sumar una fila int de Mysql dependiendo del valor de una variable

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente código para actualziar un dato Mysql con PHP:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET puntos=puntos + ? WHERE idUsuario = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('is', $puntos,$idUsuario);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Como ven estoy usando sentencias preparadas, lo que quiero hacer es sumar los puntos ya existentes en la BBDD con los puntos que estén en la variable **$puntos**

> $puntos = 17; // Es un valor de tipo entero

El código que les deje anteriromente es lo que he probado, pero me marca error.
Aunque también probé algo así:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET puntos=puntos + ".$puntos." WHERE idUsuario = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $idUsuario);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Pero tampoco funciona.

El error que marca es:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in ../.../

Agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Comment: Ayudaría mucho agregues ese error que dices obtener

Comment: @BetaM Ya he actualizado

Comment: ¿Verificaste que la conexión es correcta, que estás conectando a la BD adecuada y que esa tabla existe y que las columnas de la misma se llaman así? `$stmt` es false porque algo de eso está fallando. Es un problema de ABC de depuración de código.

Comment: ¿Probaste si la conexión a tu BD está funcionando?